# Which class of metrics should I look at?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, metric-tensor

In the context of GR, I would like to consider a spherical body (or spherical inhomogeneity) with a time dependent energy-momentum tensor immersed in some fluid, for example radiation. So I am not looking exactly at Schwarzschild because the outside is not empty and I am also not looking at an FLRW because I am violating homogeneity. Also the Weyl class seems to be static only.

Are there any cases like the above? It seems this is still a somewhat symmetric case which should be treated already.

Or is it possible for example to assume FLRW for the exterior still and perturb it somehow to glue it to an interior metric? My final goal would be to obtain an analogue of the second Friedmann equation, but it seems that it requires more modifications than I thought.